# How does one measure the size of a tallit kattan?

Tags: shiurim-measurements, tallit-katan

A Judaica store emailed me, yesterday, that they are having a 2 for 1 sale on online purchases.

I don't recall my tallit kattan size, and I don't understand the sizing numbers on the online site. I assume the measurement is in inches. But, essentially, I'm asking of someone can give me a hint as to how I should measure the size that I need.

I plan on getting the mesh ones. I don't know if the material / type of tallit kattan would make a difference in the measurements, so if it does, please put that in your answer.

Comment: American sizes are measured along the horizontal edge of the beged, AFAIK. For example, I wear an Israeli size 5 (wool) which is referred to as a size 20 over here, for the 20" width.

Comment: I would also say that per R' Moshe Feinstein, the mesh tallitot ketanot are not advisable, although CYLOR.

Comment: @DanF, check Ben's Tallit Shop, he has the measurements for all tallitot ketanot. You'll need to multiply the length by two for full length, unless you're only worried about the distance from shoulder to edge.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52836/603

Comment: Call a Judaica store and they will help you based on yiur height and weight

Comment: @Dude My weight has nothing to do with it. It's my girth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Artscroll.com](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/TZCV.html)

Size 18, 18" Wide X 22" Long

Size 20, 20" Wide X 24" Long

Size 22, 22" Wide X 26" Long

Size 24, 24" Wide X 28" Long

Size 26, 26" Wide X 30" Long

So yes each size is 2" longer & 2" wider than the previous size.

Comment: I've merged your answer from another question to this one and am letting you know just in case you want to edit it to better match the current question's wording (not that I think such editing is necessary).